# SQL Server dataset compare

Tags: sql-server

I'm validating a SQL Server data migration by comparing an expected result set generated by my SELECT statement to the data in the target data warehouse table, using EXCEPT. This only returns records that differ, not which values are different, making identification of differing column values difficult.

What I'm after is the SQL Server equivalent of the SAS proc compare(), which could return (say) the row number, key value, and the differing data item values.

Is there any (free?!!!) software or code that could do this?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Data Tools (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/tools.aspx ) can do data and schema comparisons.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx